# how to select specified fields, and return an object (defined by user) list - (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, select, projection

Hibernate api doc introduces the Criteria and Projections classes, which can help select specified fields of table and return an Object list.

BUT, i want to get an class A's list (A is defined by myself), thus i can use it as usual object list.

for example,i have a class:

```
class A {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;

    String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
...
}
```

the table in database has the same fields.

I want to select `field1` and `field2` only. so I tried:

```
List<A> list = (List<A>) ession.createCriteria(A.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                                 .add(Projections.property("field1"))
                                 .add(Projections.property("field1"))
                                 .list();
```

It is obviously not correct:  `java.lang.ClassCastException`!!

Is there any way to get a class A's list? i want to use A's method Directly, like:

```
list.get(0).getField1()
```

thks.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a projection on the criteria, the query won't return a list of entities anymore, but a list of arrays of scalars. This is a good thing, since returning a partially loaded entity would result in a multitude of bugs due to invariants being broken (non null fields being null, unloaded associations, etc.).

So, you should use another kind of object (a value object) to represent the loaded fields :

```
List<Object[]> result = criteria.list();
for (Object[] row : result) {
    AValueObject a = new AValueObject((String) row[0], (String) row[1]);
    // ...
}
```

Hibernate can also do this transformation for you, using reflection, using an `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` or an `AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer`.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if Hibernate Criteria API allows to project to objects of an arbitrary class but you can project the HQL query results to objects of an arbitrary class constructed withing HQL query by "calling" the constructor in the HQL select clause:

```
select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
   from DomesticCat as mother
   join mother.mate as mate
   left join mother.kittens as offspr
```

See [The select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) in Hibernate manual, Chapter HQL: The Hibernate Query Language.